# How do I stop right floated DIVs from pushing each other around, but only within a particular area?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am almost certain this question will get closed for having been beaten to death before, but I swear I could not find a sufficient answer, here or by Google.

I have an HTML page where the width is constrained to a certain maximum. This text also has a lot of associated images in DIV tags, that are floated along the right.

I've made an example [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8d2f6/7/) which is slightly exaggerated. The real life situation doesn't have so many floated elements. In any case, the more the containing blue bordered DIV approaches the maximum width, the vertical distance between the red bordered DIVs is not high enough, and the lower DIV gets pushed to the left.

So, **I tried adding `clear: right;` to the DIVs**, but then an added problem creeps in, which is that they clear relative to *everything*, including elements outside the containing DIV. The green bordered DIV outside the container pushes the red bordered DIVs down, which is not desired.

Is there a way to to force the red bordered DIVs to move under the DIVs above them, and constrain the effect to just within the blue containing DIV so that the green bordered DIV does not push the red bordered DIVs down? I am open to solutions that involve Javascript, though pure CSS would be ideal.

This is the CSS:

```
#otherthing {
    height: 300px;
    width: 80px;
    border: green thin solid;
    float: right;
}

#container {
 max-width: 36em;
    border: blue thin solid;
}

.test {
    border: red thin solid;
    float: right;
    clear: right;
    height: 180px;
    width:60px;
}
```

Comment: I don't see `div`s in jsfiddle. But my guess says, adding `clear:right` below `float: right` should solve your issue.

Comment: @Jashwant, whoops, I accidentally linked to an earlier edit of the JSFiddle. It's been corrected, and I've updated.

Comment: @Jashwant, I tried adding `clear: right` but in the real world example, it clears everything, so, there's a google add completely separate from the text that *also* impacts the DIVs, so they get pushed down. Is there a way to constrain the `clear` to being just within the container DIV?

Comment: You can wrap `p` and `div` inside a `div` and then clear that outer `div`

Comment: @Jashwant, thank you for your comments. I'm sorry that my clarifications are evolving the problem a little, and I've updated my question to hopefully more accurately describe the issue. I do not fully understand your last comment though. Would you be willing to expand it into an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#container {
    position: absolute;
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/aniskhan001/8d2f6/13/)** here

Comment: Thank you for this answer, but the end result is massive gaps in between P tags and the text within them. Unfortunately in my case this is not acceptable.

Comment: If you don't want any gaps between `p`s then you just simply use `clear: right` for `.test` divs.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The test DIVs already have `clear: right` on them. Please see the latest version of the question.

Comment: `position: absolute;` to the `#container` and you are good to go :)

Comment: If I do that, though, then the container DIV does not fit into the layout in the real world. It can't be assumed that the container DIV will be placed arbitrarily.

Comment: Try to put all the necessary things in the fiddle otherwise it's pretty confusing what you really want.

Comment: Yes, "the real world" follows the same rules as the fiddle so you need to include everything that will help find the correct solution. Currently, setting `position: absolute` will work with the given fiddle.

Comment: You are not being asked to put up your whole site, just the minimum that will allow people to find a robust solution. We can't guess what the rest of the site looks like.

Comment: You could use `width: calc(100% - 82px);` for `#container` so it will not overlap the `#otherthing` div. See the updated fiddle.